# Regex with jquery (Validation)

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I am creating a form and want to use a check. Here is the logic.

*Dollars should only allow `$, 0-9, ".",` and `","` characters  (i.e. $1,250.00).  it should not allow other alphanumeric characters.*

Please let me know the code.

Comment: let us know your try ... :P

Comment: Please write what have you tried so far.

Comment: `/[\$0-9\.,]/.test("$$$")` :P it's not what you realy want

Comment: this is not working.

Answer (score 1):

use the below Regex pattern to allow only "$", ".", "," and "0-9"
`/^[ 0-9.,$]*$/`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a regex that matches the following rules:

```
 - Start with a $
 - Followed by 1 or 3 numbers
 - Followed by 0 or more "," and 3 numbers
 - Ending with a "." followed by 2 numbers
```

(So it works for $1.00, $54,542.25, $999,999,999,999,999.99 but not for $45,25.00 or improper syntax)

You can use this:

```
^\$[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*\.[0-9]{2}
```

And you can add flags for better match (g or m for instance)

Answer (score -1):

This is the regex for a global search in your string:

```
/[\$0-9\.,]/g
```